# What does this mean in $R^3$ 2x-y=0

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Is this a line or a plane, I thought it would be a plane where z=0 always so it will be the xy plane.

Also: what will be the normal vector for this if it is a plane?

Comment: Hint: move $y$ to the right-hand side.

Comment: My apologies, I meant in r3 @EliRose

Answer (score 3):

It's true that $z = 0$ in the equation, but don't think of the equation as *requiring* $z = 0$ -- instead think of it as *putting no conditions* on $z$. $z$ doesn't appear in the equation, hence it can be anything.

So this is not the $xy$-plane, but a different plane: the set $\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 2x - y = 0\}$. How do we know it's a plane? I find it helpful to visualize the line $2x - y = 0$ in the $xy$-plane and then picture it "extending" to the sky and to the ground to cover all $z$.

We can always read the normal vector off a plane $ax + by + cz = 0$; it's $(a, b, c)$. So this normal vector is:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}2\\ -1\\ 0\\\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: It might be better to say that the _coefficient_ of $z$ is zero in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

It is the collection of vectors that are orthogonal to $(2,-1,0)$ and hence a plane.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, this represents a plane with normal vector $$\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$$ and is therefore perpendicular to the $z$ plane